# JavaFx 2.x: How to draw minor grid lines

Tags: java, grid, javafx-2, linechart

I'm unable to draw minor grid lines, it is possible to do so in JavaFx 2.2? In my case the grid and the graph moves so I cannot use a static image to generate the minor grid (live graph as shown in this example [here](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/products/javafx/2/samples/Ensemble/index.html#SAMPLES/Charts/Line/Advanced%20Stock%20Line%20Chart)).

Currently I see this
[image: No minor grid]

an example of what I'm looking for.
[image: with minor grid]

Comment: Have you tried adding two plot points, at (22, 0) and (22, 100), for example?

Comment: @colti I was able to generate the minor grid line as per your suggestion. There is a small flow in this approach. Look at the code http://ideone.com/W8gFZE the grid plots will contuinue joining {(1,0) and (1,100) will continue and join (2.0)}. Is there an inbuilt API that I can use instead of me plotting between end points?

Comment: if you instantiate a new Series object for each set of plot points, they won't continue. I think that is the intent with the API.

Comment: My Question still would be does JavaFx support drawing minor grid lines without the user plotting points?

Comment: As far as I can tell, no. A line segment is defined by two distinct end points. You could create methods e.g. drawVerticalLine that does the point plotting itself and takes an X co-ordinate as a parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @colti and a little bit of module logic I came up with this solution

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Axis extends Application
{

    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage stage) throws Exception
    {
        final NumberAxis x = new NumberAxis();
        final NumberAxis y = new NumberAxis();
        x.setAutoRanging(false);
        y.setAutoRanging(false);

        final LineChart<Number, Number> lineChart = new LineChart<Number, Number>(x, y);
        lineChart.setPrefSize(900, 900);
        lineChart.setLegendVisible(false);
        lineChart.setCreateSymbols(false);
        lineChart.setAlternativeColumnFillVisible(false);
        lineChart.setAlternativeRowFillVisible(false);

        final XYChart.Series seriesX = new XYChart.Series();

        for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
            if ((i % 2) != 0) {
                seriesX.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(i, 0));
                seriesX.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(i, 100));
            }
            else {
                seriesX.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(i, 100));
                seriesX.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(i, 0));
            }

        }

        final XYChart.Series seriesY = new XYChart.Series();

        for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
            if ((i % 2) != 0) {
                seriesY.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(0, i));
                seriesY.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(100, i));
            }
            else {
                seriesY.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(100, i));
                seriesY.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(0, i));
            }

        }

        lineChart.getData().add(seriesX);
        lineChart.getData().add(seriesY);
        lineChart.getStylesheets().add("site.css");
        final Scene scene = new Scene(lineChart);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

CSS

```
.chart-series-line{    
-fx-stroke-width: 1px;
-fx-stroke:#eedede;
-fx-effect: null;
}
.chart-vertical-grid-lines {
    -fx-stroke: #cccccc;
}
.chart-horizontal-grid-lines {
    -fx-stroke: #cccccc;
}
```

Comment: You should avoid hardcoding the maximum value of 100 for the x/y axis by fetching it from the `LineChart` object.

Comment: This was just a POC, I'm not hardcoding in my actual project.