# Javafx 2.2: How to implement a new Chart that extends LineChart

Tags: java, charts, javafx, javafx-2, linechart

I'm trying to implement a new chart which supports drawing minor grid lines. Earlier I tried implementing it by plotting lines [JavaFx 2.x: How to draw minor grid lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25330897/javafx-2-x-how-to-draw-minor-grid-lines). I would like to go the native route of drawing Path's instead of plotting lines.

I'm new to JavaFx and any help/guidance will be appreciated. The current code just concentrates on drawing minor horizontal grid lines.

```
public class CTChart extends LineChart
{
private final Path horizontalMinorGridLines = new Path();

public CTChart(final NumberAxis xAxis, final NumberAxis yAxis)
{
    super(xAxis, yAxis);
    this.setAnimated(false);
    this.setCreateSymbols(false);
    this.setAlternativeRowFillVisible(false);
    this.setLegendVisible(false);
    this.setHorizontalGridLinesVisible(true);
    this.setVerticalGridLinesVisible(true);

    getPlotChildren().add(horizontalMinorGridLines);
    horizontalMinorGridLines.getStyleClass().setAll("chart-horizontal-minor-grid-lines");

    int lowerBound = (int) yAxis.getLowerBound();
    int upperBound = (int) yAxis.getUpperBound();
    int tickUnit = (int) yAxis.getTickUnit();
    int minorTickCount = yAxis.getMinorTickCount();
    int minorTickUnit = tickUnit / minorTickCount;

    horizontalMinorGridLines.getElements().clear();

    for (int i = lowerBound; i < upperBound; i = i + minorTickUnit) {

        ObservableList<TickMark<Number>> tickMarks = yAxis.getTickMarks();
        for (TickMark<Number> tickMark : tickMarks) {
            tickMark.getPosition();
            // horizontalMinorGridLines.getElements().add(new MoveTo(zero, tickMark.getPosition()));
            // horizontalMinorGridLines.getElements().add(new LineTo(zero + xAxis.getWidth(), tickMark.getPosition()));
        }
    }
}
}
```

Things I'm not able to figure out

1. Am I heading in the right direction?
2. How to get the X,Y coordinates for the MoveTo and LineTo API's?
3. How to render/which code renders the minor grid lines?
4. Should everything be in the constructor?

Answer (score 0):

2. yourObject.setOnMouseMoved(event -> {
           double x = event.getX();
           double y = event.getY();
   }
3. [Example](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/charts/css-styles.htm). Use this in CSS:

   .chart-alternative-row-fill {
     -fx-fill: transparent;
     -fx-stroke: transparent;
     -fx-stroke-width: 0;
   }
4. Setting properties of the `LineChart` must be in constructor. Adding series does not have to be in constructor.